# Suggestion to make a Header based UI in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, gridbaglayout

I want to make an UI based in header and button and then content inside it.
the following screenshot will clear my objective-
I thought using gridBaglayout only (no other layout), and mention a header as a Label , but only doubt comes in mind is with different resolution and maximize minimize event , entire layout should be well enough or the effect must ideal not breaking.

[image]

Give me some suggestions to achieve the same.
My main intention is to make the header perfect , rest content can be drawn easily.

Comment: `I want to make an UI based in header and button and then content inside it.`- please make it a little bit more clear, add extra description describing the screenshot you have given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the Title section should expand when resizing. In that case I would recommend that you use a `BorderLayout`, and put the "Title" inside `BorderLayout.CENTER`, put "Section 1" and "SAVE" into `BorderLayout.NORTH` using something like a `GridLayout` or similar to keep them appart, and put "Date" in `BorderLayout.EAST`.